# Can not add a publish_stream permission

Tags: android, facebook

Hi I tryed to add public_stream permission in my app. I put to print my session iformation in my consol and I observ that when I add the public permission my session state is CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED, and when I removed this permission the session state in OPENING and I have set the other read permission.

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook_login_view, container,
            false);

    facebookButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.facebookAuth);
    facebookButton.setFragment(LoginAuthFragment.this);
    //facebookButton.setReadPermissions("email", "user_birthday");
    facebookButton.setPublishPermissions("publish_stream", "email", "user_birthday");

    return view;
}
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
   System.out.println(session);
   System.out.println("Access token: "+session.getAccessToken());

 final User u = new User();

        if(session.isOpened()){
            System.out.println("OK");
            final String subscribe;
            if(receiveMail.isChecked()){
                subscribe = "1";
            }else{
                subscribe = "0";
            }

            final String access_token=session.getAccessToken();

            Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            if (user != null) {

                                String firstName = user.getFirstName();
                                String lastName = user.getLastName();
                                String userName = "fb_user_"+user.getId();
                                String facebook_id = user.getId();
                                String birthday = user.getBirthday();
                                String email = user.asMap().get("email")
                                        .toString();
                                String response1 = u.checkFacebookUser(
                                        userName, facebook_id, access_token,
                                        birthday, email, subscribe, firstName, lastName);

                                if (response1.equals("GREEN")) {
                                    prefs.setTokenData(u.getToken(),
                                            u.getCreatedAt(), u.getExpires());
                                    Intent loggedIn = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                            MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(loggedIn);
                                    getActivity().finish();
                                } else if (response1.equals("RED")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getActivity()
                                                    .getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Unknown error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                } 

                            }

                }
            });
            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
        }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null &&
            (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}
```

And here is my session when I add publish_stream permission

> {Session state:CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:593058290740634}

And here is my session without publish_stream permission:

> {Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[email, user_birthday, user_friends, basic_info]}, appId:593058290740634}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot request publish permissions without first getting "basic_info" (which is a read permission).

The correct course of action is to first ask the user for email and user_birthday permissions, and when you're ready to publish (usually after some user interaction), then ask for publish_stream permissions.